# haskell - yet another infinite type error

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference

I am trying to solve [problem 10](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/1_to_10) from the ninety nine haskell problems.
Here is my solution that I believe is correct.

The pack function (from question 9) is already correct. The problem is with the encode function.

```
pack :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
pack [] = []
pack (x:xs) = (x : takeWhile (== x) xs) : (pack $ dropWhile (== x) xs)

encode :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
encode [] = []
encode list = (encode' $ head packed) : (encode $ tail packed)
    where packed = pack list
          encode' l = (length l, head l)
```

When I load the file from ghci, this is the error:

> encode.hs:6:0:
>       Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a = [a]
>       When generalising the type(s) for `encode'

Line 6 is the line containing `encode [] = []`

What's wrong with my encode function? I keep checking the types of the variables used and I believe there is nothing wrong.

Function usage example (assuming code is working correctly):

```
pack "aaaabbbbccccccddddddd"
> ["aaaa","bbbb","cccccc","ddddddd"]
encode "aaaabbbbccccccddddddd"
> [(4,'a'),(4,'b'),(6,'c'),(7,'d')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
encode $ tail packed
```

We have

```
packed :: [[a]]
tail packed :: [[a]]
```

But we need to pass an `[a]` to `encode`.

(Think about it like this: `list` needs to go through `pack`. `packed` is the output from `pack`, but in the recursive call it will be passed to `pack` again.)

Answer (score 4):

Recursion is somewhat clumsy here. It's much better to use a higher-order function.

You already have a function `encode' :: [a] -> (Int, a)` that encodes one sub-list, and you want to encode all of them. Applying a function to every element of a list is a very common pattern which is encapsulated by the higher-order function `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`.

Taking advantage of `map`, we can simply write:

```
encode :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
encode list = map encode' $ pack list
   where encode' xs = (length xs, head xs)
```

You can also avoid the helper function by using a list comprehension:

```
encode :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
encode list = [(length xs, head xs) | xs <- pack list]
```

In general, try to use existing higher-order functions where appropriate instead of doing your own recursion. It's both more readable and less prone to mistakes.

Comment: Both of your solutions do look much cleaner. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the function `encode` expects "unpacked" lists, but you pass a "packed" list.

Adding type signatures helps a lot here, I added a type signature for `encode'`

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

pack :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
pack [] = []
pack (x:xs) = (x : takeWhile (== x) xs) : (pack $ dropWhile (== x) xs)

encode :: forall a. (Eq a) => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
encode [] = []
encode list = (encode' $ head packed) : (encode $ tail packed)
    where packed = pack list
          encode' :: [a] -> (Int, a)
          encode' l = (length l, head l)
```

and the compiler finds the error quickly:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )

test.hs:9:42:
    Couldn't match type `a' with `[a]'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for encode :: Eq a => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
          at test.hs:8:1
    Expected type: [(Int, a)]
      Actual type: [(Int, [a])]
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `(encode $ tail packed)'
    In the expression: (encode' $ head packed) : (encode $ tail packed)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Because that would only work if `a` was the same as `[a]` and therefore the same as `[[a]]` etc. That's an infinite type error. Or simply the difference between a "packed" list (`[[a]]`) and a "unpacked" list (`[a]`) in your sample.

(For better understanding: "packed" list is a list after applying the `pack` function ;-) )

*edit: fixed ScopedTypeVariables vs. ExistentialQuantification error, thanks John L*

Comment: this looks... too advanced for me (just starting with haskell).

Comment: Let me rephrase that: The compiler tries to tell you: An "unpacked" list would be the same as a "packed" list iff `[a]` would be the same as `[[a]]`. That's true! See your definition of `pack`: `pack :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]`. `pack` transforms `[a]` to `[[a]]`. If that would be the same, "packed" and "unpacked" lists would be the same and your program would work. BUT: Then we'd have `a == [a] == [[a]] == [[[a]]] == [[[[a]]]]` so: an infinite number of "names" for the type `a`. And the compiler told you `infinite type error` :-)

Comment: Now I understand why the error is called "infinite type error"... By the way, I referred to the ExistentialQuantification thing when I said that your answer looks too advanced. I found one reference in wikibooks and it looks... well... too advanced, for now :)

Comment: Cool :-). Just ignore the ExistentialQuantification thing right now. All it does is to tell the compiler that all `a`s used in the function  `encode` are THE SAME type. `forall a.` means that the type signatures of `encode` and `encode'` specify something about an arbitraty but fixed type `a`. I wanted to tell the compiler that the two `a`s can't be a different type.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually use ExistentialQuantification; the extension which is in use is `ScopedTypeVariables`, which is implied by ExistentialQuantification.  `ScopedTypeVariables` is very simple, it just means that the `a` variable in the type of `encode'` is the same as the `a` in `encode`'s type signature.

Comment: yeah, thanks John L! I'll correct it. The pro for ExistentialQuantification is that it is supported by (nearly) all compilers for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do pattern matching on the result to pack, instead of using `head` and `tail`.
Then it looks like this:

```
encode :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
encode [] = []
encode list = encode' x : encode xs
   where (x:xs)    = pack list
         encode' l = (length l, head l)
```

The type error comes from `xs` is of type `[[a]]` because `pack`
returns `[[a]]`, but `encode` expects an `[a]` argument.

Comment: The @ operator is quite handy, is there any fancy name for it?

Comment: @Hery: they are called as-patterns, or @-patterns

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @hammar that higher-order functions are a great way to handle this problem.
Here's a general explanation of what happened, though:

Every time I've had an infinite type error, it's had the following form:
I've had a function which called itself, but called itself with a "deeper"* type than it had been passed.

Let's make a simple infinite type error:

```
*Main> let f (_:xs) = f [xs]

<interactive>:1:19:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t0 = [t0]
```

And let's break down why: the type of `f` can't be determined: If `f :: [a] -> [[a]]`, then the `f [xs] :: [[a]] -> [[[a]]]`, which gets passed to the original `f`, which can't return `[[[a]]]`.

---

*My definition of "deeper":
`[[a]]` is "deeper" than `[a]`
`Constructor (Constructor a)` is "deeper" than `Constructor a`

Comment: It can also happen the other way, for example with `f (x:_) = f x`.